# Python random number generator

Tags: python

The code works fine, but I can't figure out how to completely restart the program.  I put continue in the code and I know that is not correct, because I want it to restart completely after you guess the correct number and it displays 'Congratulations!  You guessed my number in _ guesses.

```
import random

guesses = 0
number = random.randint(1, 100)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

while guesses < 100:
    guess = int(input('Guess?  '))


    guesses = guesses + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.') 

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')

    if guess == number:
        continue

if guess == number:
    guesses = str(guesses)
    print('Congratulations!  You guessed my number in ' + guesses + '      guesses!')
```

Comment: Just put the whole thing inside a while loop like "while True" and then ask if they want to continue and break if the answer is no

Comment: Thanks for the help, this solution would work but I want the program to restart automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep on guessing and start the game automatically, you need to do a recursive call:

```
import random 

def guess_func():
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    guesses = 0
    while True:
        guess = int(raw_input("Enter your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print('Your guess is too low.')
            guesses += 1

        if guess > number:
            print('Your guess is too high.')
            guesses += 1

        if guess == number:
            print "Congratulations! You guessed my number in [{}] guesses".format(guesses)
            print "Let's keep on guessing!"
            return guess_func()

guess_func()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help changed my code to fit this format, but one thing I noticed is that unless you change the guesses under def guess_func to 1 the number of guesses in the last statement is off by one.

Answer (score 0):

so like this:

```
while True:
    guesses = 0

    while guesses < 100:
        if guesses == 100:
            break
            ...
        if guess == number:
            print ...

    yorn = input "do you want to try again?") 
    if yorn == 'n':
        break
```

so just wrap your code in an outer while, obviously i skipped a lot of your code